# Stiffness in bldc position loop

Tags: control-system, servo, controller

I implemented a position loop using lead lag compensator on bldc motor drive. I am not getting stiffness at required position. Can anyone help with the issue.

---

Max tolerance 0.01deg with the reference position

Comment: What's stiffness ?

Comment: Do you have a general idea of either the transfer function or frequency response of your motor ?

Comment: Yes the response i got from signal analyser

Comment: Any load applied at required position.it shouldn't move to any other positions

Comment: you should define a maximum tolerance. For example, ± 1 mm or something.

Comment: Is there too much overshoot when going from position A or position B ?

Or, when in position A there is too much "jitter"

Comment: No not exactly but no stiffness is there at that point

Comment: so you mean that at position A, you feel like it's not stiff enough?

It seems like you a got a disturbance rejection problem.

Comment: Max tolerance 0.01 degree per what unit torque?

Comment: @Ben yes exactly

Comment: @BrianDrummond yes

Comment: Consider adding an integrator or a lag filter (i.e., increase gain at very DC, low frequencies). Alternately, increase the bandwidth, if you want stiffness for rapidly varying externally applied torques also. What is the disturbance torque ? gravity ?

Comment: @AJN disturbance torque is the pressure coming when middle is fired. That exerted pressure has to be callibrated using motor current

Comment: @user244617 I didn't understand your comment (middle is fired ? calibrated ?). At steady state, the motor torque = disturbance torque. Motor current = motor torque / torque constant. motor current = DC gain of the control * permissible error. What do you get when you do these calculations for your system. Your question contains too few details. Add more details.

Comment: @AJN the force exerted while firing missile has to be callibrated with bldc motors. For that i had implemented position loop so that it should be in required position even if any disturbance comes. The current drawn by the motor indicates how much torque exerted on the motor, with that torque we derive force exerted from it. This is our idea

Comment: From this description, i think you need, not just *stiffness* at steady state, but also during transients. Increase the bandwidth of the system (Actually, you need to improve the disturbance rejection. Bandwidth increase usually improves disturbance rejection properties also). The question contains too few details.

Comment: It's still not clear what stiffness (torque per unit deflection) you are looking for.